# Can I still use the ELK stack with Jhipster v7+?

Tags: jhipster, elastic-stack

I'd like to use the ELK stack to visualize data from jhipster similar to the jhipster console that was supported in pre V7 jhipster. Is it still possible to use ELK stack with the newer versions of jhipster or can I install old versions of jhipster and use those?

Comment: Did you run into a specific issue? There was a recent PR around compatibility, but IMO it should all keep working.

Comment: Everytime I start jhipster elasticsearch shutsdown immediately after so I can't use kibana

Comment: Do you have anything (interesting) in the Elasticsearch logs? Don't think that's the way it should behave, but it could either be a resource issue or a bad command to shut it down?